# Finding probability of Sample standard deviation given population is normally distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

For a random sample of size $n,$ if the values are taken from the $N(a, b)$ population, what is the probability that $S$ (where $S^2$ is sample variance) will exceed a particular value?
I had 2 approaches in mind here. Please let me know which one is correct

1. Since $(n-1) S^2/\sigma^2$ is chi square distributed, can I say the square root of term on LHS is normally distributed?
2. Use $x-\mu/(S/\sqrt{n})$ which is t distributed to find the answer

Comment: The square root of a chi-squared distributed random variable is never negative and has a chi distribution

Comment: @Henry ohh alright! what could be an approach to the problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I didn't get which LHS you meant, but the square root of $\chi^2(n)$ is not normal (or maybe it's not what you meant). Also you almost found the credible interval you were looking for. Since $\cfrac{(n - 1) S^2}{\sigma^2}$ is $H = \chi^2(n-1)$ you may just say $\mathbb{P} \Bigg( \chi^2_{\frac{\alpha}{2}, n-1} \leq H \leq \chi^2_{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}, n-1} \Bigg) = 1 - \alpha$, multiply the insides by $\sigma^2$ and get $\mathbb{P} \Bigg( \cfrac{(n - 1) S^2}{\chi^2_{\frac{\alpha}{2}, n-1}} \leq \sigma^2 \leq \cfrac{(n - 1) S^2}{\chi^2_{1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}, n-1}} \Bigg) = 1 - \alpha$. For exactly $\sigma$ and not $\sigma^2$ you can take a square root then. Also notice $S^2$ is the unbiased sample variance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the $n > 1$ part, and I'd call it a 'probability interval', not a 'confidence interval' because we're not estimating $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2.$ Anyhow, on the right track, (+1).

Comment: Actually that $n > 1$ part is useless, forget about that. And yeah maybe it's better to call it a probability interval.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem for a specific case:
Suppose $n = 10, \sigma = 15,$ and your desired
cutoff value $c$ has $c^2 = 200.$

Then, $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1).$ So
$$P(S > c) =P(S^2 > c^2) = P\left(\frac{9S^2}{225} > \frac{9(200)}{225} = 8\right)\\ = P(Q > 8) = 1 - P(Q\le 8) = 0.5341,$$
where $Q\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=9).$ You can evaluate this
probability (at least approximately) from printed tables
of chi-squared distributions or (exactly) by using software. Using R, where `pchisq` is a chi-squared CDF, the answer is obtained as follows:

```
1 - pchisq(8, 9)
[1] 0.5341462
```

In the figure below, you want the area under the density curve to the right of the vertical dotted line.

[image]

```
curve(dchisq(x, 9), 0, 30, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", xlab="q", main="")
abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
abline(v = 8, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```